# sharing a map with boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am writing a multithreaded program that uses `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` for some reason.

Let's assume it is basically a word count. Each thread counts the occurrences of the words it finds in an input file and puts them in a local map. There is a global map in my segment of shared memory, so I want to insert what every thread has found into the global map. In addition to that, threads are looping over a set of files, so they are repeating this operation multiple times.

I followed the tutorial I found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map) to create my shared map. The difference in my case is that the key is a string and the value is an unsigned int:

```
typedef std::string    KeyType;
typedef unsigned int   MappedType;
typedef std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType> ValueType;

typedef bip::allocator<ValueType, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef bip::map<KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MyMap;
```

The main program creates the segment of shared memory and allocates the shared map inside, as well as a mutex:

```
bip::managed_shared_memory segment( bip::create_only, SEGNAME,  SEGSIZE ); 
ShmemAllocator alloc_inst( segment.get_segment_manager() );
MyMap *wcmap = segment.construct<MyMap>("WCmap")( std::less<KeyType>(), alloc_inst );
bip::named_mutex map_mutex( bip::create_only, "map_mutex" );
```

Only after that does the main program spawn the threads. The said threads execute a function that opens the segment of shared memory and the mutex:

```
bip::managed_shared_memory segment( bip::open_only, SEGNAME ); 
bip::named_mutex map_mutex( bip::open_only, "map_mutex" );
```

Then it enters a loop over the files it has to deal with, and at the end of every iteration, I want it to insert its result into the global map:

```
/* Perform the computation */
bip::map<KeyType, MappedType> localwc = countwords( fname );
map_mutex.lock();
/* Do I need to find it at every iteration? */
std::pair<MyMap*, std::size_t> pMap = segment.find<MyMap>( "WCmap" );
MyMap* globalwc = pMap.first;
/* Perform the insertion itself */           
for (auto const& [key, val] : localwc){
  (*globalwc)[key] += val;
}
map_mutex.unlock();
```

My code segfaults at `(*globalwc)[key] += val;`. I suspect that the map itself has been moved around the segment of shared memory once it has reached a certain size, am I correct?

I tried to dereference the pointer to my map, but of course, in this case the data I am handling in the loop was disappearing

```
MyMap globalwc = *(pMap.first);
/* Perform the insertion itself */           
for (auto const& [key, val] : localwc){
  globalwc[key] += val;
}
```

So, to summarize my question: how do I access / handle / manipulate maps that are located in a shared memory segment?

Comment: I think you need to read the "container of containers" link at the bottom of the linked tutorial as the key you want to use is also a container.

Comment: You need to check first if 'key' has already been inserted as a key in globalwc and if not, initialize it with globalwc[key] = 0

Comment: Hi, I realize I tried stuff following your recommendation and I never came back to thank you @RichardCritten. Thanks a lot, I realized I needed to work a little bit more on the definition of how my container is supposed to be handled in the segment of shared memory!